# gensim docvecs.doctags incorrect indices

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I'm working with a large dataset of Yelp reviews for a machine learning research project. Gensim has worked well so far, however, when I build the vocabulary with `doc2vec.build_vocab()` on the over 5,000,000 documents I have...the indices appear to all be collected into a 64-key dictionary (which should certainly not be the case).

Below is the script I made for tagging the documents, building the vocabulary, and training the model.

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

# keras helper function
def text2_word_seq(review):
  return text_to_word_sequence(review, 
       filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', 
       lower=True, split=" ")

# instantiate the model
d2v = Doc2Vec(vector_size=300, 
  window=6, min_count=5, workers=os.cpu_count()-1)

chunksize = 5000
train_data = pd.read_json("dataset/review.json",
    chunksize=chunksize,
    lines=True)

Review = namedtuple('Review', 'words tags')
documents = list()
for i, data in enumerate(train_data):
    print("Looked at %d chunks, %d documents" % 
       (i, i*chunksize), end='\r', flush=True)
    users = data.user_id.values
    for j, review in enumerate(data.text):
        documents.append(Review(text2_word_seq(review), users[j]))

# build the vocabulary 
d2v.build_vocab(documents.__iter__(), update=False,
   progress_per=100000, keep_raw_vocab=False, trim_rule=None)

# train the model
d2v.train(documents, total_examples=len(documents), epochs=10)
d2v.save('d2v-model-v001')
```

After saving the model and loading it with `genim.models.Doc2Vec.load()`, the model's `docvecs.doctags` is of length 64. Each tag I am using when building the vocabulary is a user id. It is not necessarily unique, but there are thousands of users (not 64). Also, the tags appear as single characters - which is not expected...

```
>>> len(x.docvecs.doctags)
```

64

```
>>> x.docvecs.doctags

{'Y': Doctag(offset=27, word_count=195151634, doc_count=1727798), 
'j': Doctag(offset=47, word_count=198241878, doc_count=1739169), 
'4': Doctag(offset=17, word_count=195902251, doc_count=1728095), 
'J': Doctag(offset=50, word_count=197884244, doc_count=1741666), 
'W': Doctag(offset=41, word_count=198804200, doc_count=1741269), 
'O': Doctag(offset=23, word_count=196212468, doc_count=1728735), 
'o': Doctag(offset=9, word_count=194177928, doc_count=1709768), 
'n': Doctag(offset=3, word_count=193799059, doc_count=1714620), 
'3': Doctag(offset=34, word_count=197320036, doc_count=1725467), 
'F': Doctag(offset=10, word_count=195614702, doc_count=1729058) ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tags` property of your text examples should be a list-of-tags. (It can be a list containing just a single tag, but it must be a list.)

If you provide a string instead, that will look like a list-of-one-character-strings to the code expecting a lis. Thus you'll train just a small number of single-character-tags, one per unique character appearing in any of the `tags` strings you provided.

Comment: What an incredible mistake. Thank you for your answer!